# Return JSON response for errors when request's content-type is JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails application that renders ERB's and also a separate namespace for API endpoints.

When there's an error, say 404, or some un-rescued exception...etc, rails is returning errors in HTML.

I'm unclear on how/where to put an error handler that will respond in JSON when the request's content-type is JSON.

In my API Base Controller I have
`ruby
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: ->(e) { render_error(e, :not_found) }`

And am able to capture specific errors, but I'd like to have a larger wrapper that is taking care of any unhandled exceptions. Any advice on good practices for this?

Rails 4.2.4
Ruby 2.1.5

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have handled this situation in my application

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :not_found

  def not_found
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :file => File.join(Rails.root, 'public', '404.html') }
      format.json { render :text => '{"error": "Record not found"}' }
    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively,

> you can use this **request.format.json?** to find out the kind of request
>   and based on that you render either json or html.

Comment: Extending on what I think is a good answer - what I've seen done often is having an ErrorHandlerConcern which you include in your base controller, and define all the methods for appropriately rescuing different kinds of exceptions in there.